# invoking chaincode using hyperledger-fabric-client using grpcs and intermediate certificates

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, grpc

we've setup a Hyperledger Fabric network and installed the fabcar sample (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/fabcar) on it ... we are using grpcs to communicate but for some reason the hyperledger-client-sdk doesn't want to connect to our Peer. It just gives us the following error in the logs without any further explanation: 
`[client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect`

- which PEM file we should give to the `newPeer()` function? or the `grpc.credentials.createSsl()` function because this one is used in the back ... https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release/fabric-client/lib/Remote.js#L149
- how should we structure this one, which certificates should be in it when using intermediate certificates?

We don't see anything appearing in the logs on the Peer even though the Peer receives tcp packets when the proposal is sent.

We also tried to invoke the chaincode using the cli and this works without any problems.

Kind regards,

Daan

Comment: [This link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-sample-application-ibm-blockchain-platform/index.html) shows how to extract the PEM you're looking for - it provides a file called `extractCerts.js` which shows how to grab the files from the CA.

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this issue? i am facing the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PEM file must contain the list of certificates from the root to the peer, one after another. You must also set the `ssl-target-name-override` option of `newPeer()` to the peer hostname corresponding to the CN field of the peer certificate.

Comment: can you elaborate about the PEM file must contain the list of certificats from root to peer? the PEM file is generated by gryptogen and is already placed in the the tls folder, did you modify it? I am experiencing the same problem as OP, and did set the ssl-taget-name-override to the CN field of my PEM but still no luck.

Comment: please have a look [here](https://github.com/Kunstmaan/hyperledger-fabric-kuma-token-example), in the `network/generated/crypto-config/` folder you have examples of certificates. You just have to put all the certificates in the same file, from the root of the certificate chain up to the peer.

Comment: for example, to create a peer for the org.kunstmaan.be, we use this TLS certificate: `network/generated/crypto-config/org.kunstmaan.be/peers/kumapeer.org.kunstmaan.be/tlsca.combined.kumapeer.org.kunstmaan.be-cert.pem`
As you can see, this certificate is just all the certificates from root to the peer, just appended one after the other.

Comment: how can you set the ssl-target-name-override option of newPeer()?